# Cordova android geolocation timeout

Tags: android, ios, cordova, geolocation

I'm getting mad at trying to make geolocation working on Android
I followed steps as explained in Cordova documentation pages
My cordova version is 3.1.0-0.2.0

```
$ cordova create myApp com.mymapackage.myApp myApp
$ cordova platform add ios
$ cordova platform add android
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation
```

AndroidManifest contains

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

app/res/xml/config.xml contains

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker" />
</feature>
```

I also copied the simple example to tryout geolocation

```
// Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { timeout: 30000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
    }

    // onSuccess Geolocation
    //
    function onSuccess(position) {
        var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
        element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
                'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
                'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                'Timestamp: '          + position.timestamp                    + '<br />';
    }

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }
```

and all I can get is a timeout error.
I have tried on many different target version/devices with ADT emulator, Genymotion emulator and cannot get anything out of geolocation position.
By adding ios platform it was quite straight forward having location information when emulating using xCode.

I'm starting getting desperate with this thing. Any idea that could help?

Comment: Have you tried on an actual android device? If you are just trying on the emulator you will probably have to do some extra stuff to fake geolocation information. Do you get any errors in logcat besides the timeout?

Comment: this is where I'm getting desperate, no errors related to position fetching and does not work on actual device as well.

Comment: Did you enable location services on the device? Did you also run `cordova build`?

Comment: I just tried on an Android device (Nexus 7) running 4.3  with the example and it is working fine. I did create, add android, add the plugin, copy the "full example" from the docs into `/www/index.html`, ran `cordova build`, ran `cordova run`.

Comment: Finallay I managed to make it working using Genymotion emulator.
I did not run cordova build but will try.
Now I have deployed my app to my galaxy s2 and it's still a pb to get the location, timeout and looks like it cannot find any position depsite the network location is activated

Comment: Hey, are you still having issues with this? I realized that when we test this with mobile spec, the cordova geolocation plugin fails with Android, but the regular browser-based geolocation works fine.  Read through the test page: https://github.com/apache/cordova-mobile-spec/blob/master/location/index.html#L141 Try using `navigator.geolocation` without using the plugin.

Comment: Hmm If you Still have This Issue, Can You SHed More Light If The On Error Function Is Executed Or Not?

Answer (score 1):

There is already issues reported upstream very similar to yours : "Geolocation watchPosition consistently timing out on Android 4.0.4 with Cordova 3.3.0" (issue.apache.org)

Moreover the cordova geolocation plugin is known to have multiple issues and will be deprecated soon[1].

The solution is to use regular browser-based geolocation. The test given by MBillau[2] tries to use geolocation via the plugin and via the browser.

The last option is to go native or to write your own plugin.

[1] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5977

[2] https://github.com/apache/cordova-mobile-spec/blob/master/location/index.html